# How to skip a dependency if related feature is disabled

Tags: dependencies, rust, conditional-compilation, rust-cargo, rust-crates

Suppose I have a crate which depends on the `glob` crate only if `#[cfg(feature = "glob")]` is enabled. Also, this feature is disabled by default. How can I skip downloading and compiling of the `glob` crate by default?

```
# Cargo.toml
...
[features]
default = []

[dependencies]
glob = "0.2"
...
```

And the source code:

```
# lib.rs
.. several uses

#[cfg(feature = "glob")]
extern crate glob;

... a lot of code that doesn't use glob crate.

#[cfg(feature = "glob")]
impl Foo for Bar { 
    // only this code uses glob crate 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `glob` dependency must be marked as optional:

```
[dependencies]
glob = { version = "0.2", optional = true }
```